# I'm trying to separate my jquery code from the html, but it's not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this html page, which works as planned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Autocomplete</title>
    <meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

        <div data-role="header">
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <p>
                <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
                <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script>

        $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {

            var data = ['C', 'Clojure', 'Jenny!', 'Java', 'Scala', 'Objective-C', 'C++', 'PHP', 'C#', '(Visual) Basic', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Visual Basic .NET', 'Transact-SQL', 'Lisp', 'Pascal', 'Bash', 'PL/SQL', 'Delphi/Object Pascal', 'Ada', 'MATLAB'];

            $("#searchField").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: data,
                link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1,
                matchFromStart: false
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to put the part between the script tags into a file called listview.js, and replace what is currently between the script tags with something like:

```
      $(function() {
  initialize_listview();
  });
```

So my function in listview.js at present looks like, but it's not working:

```
function initialize_listview() {

$("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {

            var data = ['C', 'Clojure', 'Jenny!', 'Java', 'Scala', 'Objective-C', 'C++', 'PHP', 'C#', '(Visual) Basic', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Visual Basic .NET', 'Transact-SQL', 'Lisp', 'Pascal', 'Bash', 'PL/SQL', 'Delphi/Object Pascal', 'Ada', 'MATLAB'];

            $("#searchField").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: data,
                link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1,
                matchFromStart: false
            });
        });

}
```

Can anyone fix it for me, so it works exactly as if it were all in the same file? Thanks. And I know I have to put:

```
<script src="listview.js"></script>
```

in my header.

Comment: Include listview.js after jquery.js(Make sure that the order is correct)

Comment: check for any error in console in red!

Comment: no, no red errors. yes, listview.js is after jquery.js, but still not working.thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hooking your code twice (to two different events)... Your `initialize_listview()` is hooked up to the `document.ready` event, and the code inside `initialize_listview` is hooking up to the page show event...

Try this, replace what is currently between the script tags with this:

```
$("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
    initialize_listview();
}
```

and in your listview.js

```
function initialize_listview() {
    var data = ['C', 'Clojure', 'Jenny!', 'Java', 'Scala', 'Objective-C', 'C++', 'PHP', 'C#', '(Visual) Basic', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Visual Basic .NET', 'Transact-SQL', 'Lisp', 'Pascal', 'Bash', 'PL/SQL', 'Delphi/Object Pascal', 'Ada', 'MATLAB'];

        $("#searchField").autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: data,
            link: 'target.html?term=',
            minLength: 1,
            matchFromStart: false
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put that `script` tag at the bottom of your page. It's loading and immediately running, before your page has finished loading. `#mainpage` hasn't been parsed to the DOM yet, so the script can't find it. By putting the `script` tag at the bottom of the page, you're ensuring that the whole page has finished loading before the script runs, and your javascript code will be able to find all the page elements that it needs.

Comment: They could also use `$(document).ready()` if they want put it anywhere in the file without having to worry about if the DOM is ready.

Comment: Also true. Most jQuery code should be wrapped in `$(function () { ... })`. But, putting it at the bottom of the page is generally seen as best practice, because it's better for performance.

Comment: @bastos.sergio yes, it is!

Comment: @MattDiamant - thanks for that, wanted to up you 1 but apparently I need a rep of 15. It worked when I moved all the script tags (except for jquery1.8.2, leaving it where it is) and was going to mark correct answer, but bastos' code works with all the tags still left at the top. Just want to keep it consistent!